# Javascript - search for HTML elements in string

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, text

I have string with html elements. There are tables with captions. I need to find table which has caption with certain text and then return this table - as a string.

What is the best way to do this with simple javascript, without any libraries ?

F.e. this is an initial string

```
<table border="1"><caption><strong>First</strong></caption><tbody><tr><td>...</td></tr></tbody></table><table border="1"><caption><strong>Result</strong></caption><tbody><tr><td>...</td></tr></tbody></table><table border="1"><caption><strong>Last</strong></caption><tbody><tr><td>...</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I want to get this string :

```
<table border="1"><caption><strong>Result</strong></caption><tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Any advice or algorithm how to effeciently resolve this problem ? The challenge is to resolve it with javascript without using any third-party libraries and also without converting text into xml or something similar (because some of html code is not well formatted and it causes errors).

Comment: Then correct the generated HTML to avoid those errors, and then do this properly using DOM parsing. Don't create a second problem to avoid fixing the first.

Comment: it is not possible due to several issues, html code is generated by another system, I just receive this ugly string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not had time to completely test this, but you might be able to try using a regular expression and the match() function.  Assuming your table string is in a variable called str, then something along the lines of

```
var res = str.match(\b<table\.\w+_</table>\b);
```

res will be an array of matches of strings that begin with '', which you could then check to see which string contains the caption that you need.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I use something similar (/<table\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/table>/gm) but you show me the way. Thanks !